# Can this change in subclass require recompilation of code dependent on superclass?

Tags: c++, g++, vtable

I have been learning some more "indepth" things about virtual tables recently and this question came to my mind.

Suppose we have this sample:

```
class A {
 virtual void foo();
}

class B : public A {
 void foo();
}
```

In this case from what I know there will be a vtable present for each class and the dispatch would be quite simple.

Now suppose we change the B class to something like this:

```
class B : public C, public A {
  void foo();
}
```

If the class C has some virtual methods the dispatch mechanism for B will be more complicated. There will probably be 2 vtables for both inheritance paths B-C, B-A etc.

From what I've learned so far it seems that if there would be somewhere else in the codebase function like this:

```
void bar(A * a) {
  a->foo();
}
```

It would need to compile now with the more complicated dispatch mechanism because at compile time we do not know if "a" is pointer to A or B.

Now to the question. Suppose we added the new class B to our codebase. It doesn't seem likely to me that it would require to recompile the code everywhere where the pointer to A is used.

From what I know the vtables are created by the compiler. However is it possible that this fixup is solved by the linker possibly during relocation? It does seem likely to me I just can not find any evidence to be sure and therefore go to sleep right now :)

Comment: Subclass and superclass are not correct C++ terms. They are called "derived class" and "base class".

Comment: The only thing that would necessarily require re-compiling code using A would be a change in the declaration/interface of the method. So the question is more what does the linker do exactly? Which kind of mistake we can do in the linking process that will cause a runtime error? Will be these errors detected, causing abort, or some undefined/unpredictable runtime behavior is possible?

Comment: "There will probably be 2 vtables for both inheritance paths B-C, B-A etc." Nope.  B still has only one vtable, though it could have two vtable _pointers_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `void bar(A * a)`, the pointer is definitely to an `A` object. That `A` object may be a subobject of something else like a `B`, but that's irrelevant. The `A` is self-contained and has its own vtable pointer which links to `foo`.

When the conversion from `B *` to `A *` occurs, such as when `bar` is called with a `B *`, a constant offset may be added to the `B *` to make it point to the `A` subobject. If the first thing in every object is the vtable, then this will also set the pointer to the `A` vtable as well. For single inheritance, the adjustment is unnecessary.

Here is what memory looks like for a typical implementation:

```
| ptr to B vt | members of C | members of B | ptr to AB vt | members of A |

B vt: | ptrs to methods of C (with B overrides) | ptrs to methods of B |
AB vt: | ptrs to methods of A (with B overrides) |
```

(Note that typically the `AB vt` is really still part of the `B vt`; they would be contiguous in memory. And `ptrs to methods of B` could then go after `ptrs to methods of A`. I just wrote it this way for formatting clarity.)

When you convert a `B *` to an `A *`, you go from this:

```
| ptr to B vt | members of C | members of B | ptr to AB vt | members of A |
^ your B * pointer value
```

to this:

```
| ptr to B vt | members of C | members of B | ptr to AB vt | members of A |
                                            ^ your A * pointer value
```

Using a `static_cast` from `A *` to `B *` will move the pointer backwards, in the other direction.

Comment: I don't see why the `AB` table couldn't be _inside_ of `B`'s table..  `B` should only need one `vtable`.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Sure, typically there will be one section of memory containing member function pointers and such things for class B, and its two vptrs will point to different parts of that memory.  Whether it's one vtable with multiple sections or two vtables that happen to be adjacent is just a description.  (Okay, typically there's just the one linker symbol too.)

Comment: Specifically I'm curious as to why you put `ptrs to methods of B` in the same table as `ptrs to methods of C`, but separate from `ptrs of methods of A`. (Also, aren't A's members typically between C's members and B's members?  I always assumed they were, but I don't know anything about that)

Comment: @MooingDuck Just to simplify and fit each idea on one line. What aschepler said is the general idea. The `AB` and purely `B` functions can go anywhere except at the start of the `B` vtable, including into an entirely separate table. But it might as well be inside the same linker object. If the ones introduced by `B` were in such an alternative location, they wouldn't be found after the pointer at the beginning of the most-derived (B) object, which would be unintuitive.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Actually I knew about the data layout, but I didn't know (which is more important) that polymorphism is implemented this way. That when you assign pointer to B to the pointer to A that the values of the pointers are different. Actually when I think about it, that behavior is quite expected.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no need to recompile the code that depends only on `A`.

This is actually immediately follows from the principle of "independent translation", which typical modern C++ compilers adhere to. You can write all code dependent only on `A` in such a way, that it will never include any definitions that mention `B`. That means that any changes in `B` will not trigger the recompilation of any `A`-specific code. That in turn means that a C++ compiler that follows the principle of "independent translation" has to implement simple inheritance, multiple inheritance, virtual dispatch, hierarchical conversions etc. in such a way that any changes in `B`-specific code do not require recompilation of any `A`-specific code.

If that wasn't the case, the architecture of a typical C++ compiler would have to be significantly different.